# How to pass error handling to a function in PHP?

Tags: php, laravel, error-handling

I need to handle multiple types of error in many places in my PHP class in my Laravel project, and of course I don't want to repeat error handling codes everywhere in my code.

I have this code now:

```php
class MyAwesomeClass {
    public function parseItems(Request $request) {
        // do something

        try {
            // ...
        } catch (Exception $error) {
            $this->handleError($error);
        }
    }

    public function handleError(Exception $error) {
        $type = get_class($error);

        switch ($type) {
            case 'TypeAException':
                return response([
                    'message' => 'My custom message for Type A error',
                    'status' => 'Error',
                    'errors' => []
                ], 500);

            case 'TypeBException':
                return response([
                    'message' => 'My custom message for Type B error',
                    'status' => 'Error',
                    'errors' => []
                ], 500);

            default:
                // ...
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

But the `handleError()` method isn't called.

How can I pass the exceptions to my error handler method in PHP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Laravel, error and exception handling is already configured for you. No need to use custom class to achieve this.

All exceptions are handled by the `App\Exceptions\Handler` class, you may customize `report` and `render` methods on this class:

```php
/**
 * Render an exception into an HTTP response.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @param  \Throwable  $exception
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function render($request, Throwable $exception)
{
    if ($exception instanceof TypeAException) {
        return response([
            'message' => 'My custom message for Type A error',
            'status' => 'Error',
            'errors' => []
        ], 500);
    }
    else if ($exception instanceof TypeBException) {
        return response([
            'message' => 'My custom message for Type B error',
            'status' => 'Error',
            'errors' => []
        ], 500);
    }

    return parent::render($request, $exception);
}
```

See [Error Handling](https://laravel.com/docs/master/errors) on Laravel docs for more info.